# How to ensure that CodeIgniter controller and action exists

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have to create a function that will check whether CodeIgniter's controller and action exists. The framework has non-reusable method `Router::_validate_request()` which checks whether the file exists, but I don't like it `:)`

I'm trying to figure out what is the best way since they don't use any autoload functions and php's [class_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php) and [method_exists](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) are useless.

Comment: Why are they useless? What you don't like of the core method? You still need to check if the file exists, include it, and see if the class exits, and then if method exists. All the things you want to avoid, that is.

Comment: @DamienPirsy when you don't have an autoload method you these functions will always return false. And about the core method - it does not checks if the action exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a custom function that uses `file_exists` (like in `Router::_validate_request()`) and then use `ReflectionClass` to find the method.